# Moving to Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

What is the Facebook PHP SDK 4 equivalent of

```
facebook_client()->api(array(
    'method' => 'auth.revokeAuthorization',
    'uid' => $fbuid,
));
```

?

I could not find such documentation for FacebookRequest class

Comment: That seems to be an outdated REST API method. What exactly is it supposed to do? (I could guess, but I can’t find any documentation for it, so maybe best if you described what you actually want to achieve here.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'DELETE',
    '/me/permissions'
);
$response = $request->execute();
```

That was really deprecated REST API only functionality